# Android does interface method called in which thread ? sync or async?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I know it is a very question. I am trying to implement a callback mechanism.

I have a java Class in Android  and inside i have an interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

        public void cb1(Integer id);
        public void cb2(Integer id);
    };
```

User can use my Interface and implement, and whenever i need to inform to the user  , i will invoke cb1() or cb2().

**Question:**

Let's say user have provided me implementation of interface mInterface,

```
 while (1) {
     mInterface.cb1()
 }
```

1) In which thread cb1() will get invoked ? sync call or async call ?

2) if async call, what if the implementation of cb1() blocks for some time? Will all the cb1() calls delivered to the user one by one ?

Answer (score 4):

In the code above it will be a synchronous call. If you want it to be async, you should create a new `Thread` to perform the callback on.

Answer (score -1):

Odd question. The code will be async relative to the main thread if it is not executed on the main thread. Otherwise it will be sync and is executed on the main thread